# Ktor: Mock Principal

Tags: ktor

I have following route:

```
   get("/user") {
        val principal: UserIdPrincipal = call.principal()
            ?: return@get call.respond(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
        val user = userService.findUserForId(principal.name.toLong())
            ?: return@get call.respond(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)

        val userResponse = UserResponse(username = user.username)
        call.respond(userResponse)
    }
```

I don't want to test if authentication works for every single of my routes, so I would like to mock `call.principal()`. Since it is an inline extension function, it cannot be easily mocked. Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you can change the configuration for the [Authentication](https://ktor.io/docs/authentication.html) plugin in a test then you can register a provider, intercept its pipeline in the `AuthenticationPipeline.RequestAuthentication` phase, to get an access to authentication context, and finally assign new principal. Here is an example:

```
import io.ktor.application.*
import io.ktor.auth.*
import io.ktor.response.*
import io.ktor.routing.*
import io.ktor.server.engine.*
import io.ktor.server.netty.*

fun main() {
    val server = embeddedServer(Netty, port = 8080) {
        install(Authentication) {
            provider {
                pipeline.intercept(AuthenticationPipeline.RequestAuthentication) { context ->
                    context.principal(UserIdPrincipal("principal"))
                }
            }
        }

        routing {
            authenticate {
                get("/user") {
                    val principal: UserIdPrincipal = call.principal()!!
                    call.respond(principal.name)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    server.start(wait = true)
}
```

Comment: any idea how to por this to ktor 2.2? provider and pipeline intercept dont exists anymore

Answer (score 0):

In your test you could

```
install(Authentication) {
            register(MockAuthenticationProvider(DummyConfig("name")))
        }
```

where

```
val jwtPrincipal = mockk<JWTPrincipal>()
class MockAuthenticationProvider(config: Config) : AuthenticationProvider(config) {
                override suspend fun onAuthenticate(context: AuthenticationContext) {
                    context.principal(jwtPrincipal)
                }
            }
    
class DummyConfig(name: String) : AuthenticationProvider.Config(name)
```